# Trying to make invisible text appear if something is wrong in textfield

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code html part:

```
<form>

    <p>First Name:
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"    /> 
        <span id="firstnameInvalid" style="color:red; visibility:hidden"> Name is Invalid </span>
    </p>


<input id="submitme" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Here is the Javascript part in the head

```
window.addEventListener("load",start);


function start(){
  document.getElementById('submitme').onclick=function(e){
       e.preventDefault();   checkme();} ;
    document.getElementById('firstname').onkeydown=function(e);

}
function checkme(){
    alert('inside checkme');
    var firstname=document.getElementById('firstname');
    if(firstname ==""){
        document.getElementById("firstnameInvalid").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

}
```

So when i push submit it doesnt do anything, not even an alert box will pop up so i never even reach the check me function.

Comment: `function(e);` with no body on line 7 should cause a SyntaxError. So none of you code is ever run.

Comment: Also, a more semantic way to do this is to add the `required` attribute to the text field. That will prevent form submission while the field is empty, and the UI may provide some feedback to the user, all without any JavaScript.